# ¿Cómo posiciono el logo encima del menú?

Tags: css, bootstrap

¿Hola, qué tal?

He intentado posicionar el logo en el centro del menú sin ningún éxito. Lo que he logrado es ponerlo junto con los elementos "Contacto" y las redes sociales... Pero todo se pone blanco y no lo necesito así.

Lo que necesito es que medio logo esté dentro del menú y que la otra mitad se muestre en la imagen que está debajo.

He buscado en muchas partes y también he verificado si mi pregunta está duplicada pero no he tenido éxito. También he intentado con `position:fixed;` y con `z-index: 10000;` y demás pero no logro organizar lo que necesito.

Agradezco que me puedan ayudar. ¡Un abrazo!

[image: Logo debajo del menú]

---

**Editado: Agregaré el código que tengo.**

**Estoy usando Bootstrap 4**

Mi código hasta ahora:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-top">
          <div class="col-sm-12 pt-2 pb-2">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-left mt-2 mb-2 my-auto">
                      <a target="_blank" href="#">
                         Contacto
                      </a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 text-right mt-2 mb-2 my-auto">
                       <a target="_blank" href="#" class="text-white btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-circle-sm m-1">
                            <i class="lni-facebook-filled"></i>
                       </a>

                       <a target="_blank" href="#" class="text-white btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-circle-sm m-1">
                            <i class="lni-instagram-original"></i>
                       </a>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
       <a href="#">
           <img src="img/logo-rinoff.png" width="160" class="img-fluid d-block ml-auto" alt="" style=" margin-top: -50px;">
       </a> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: deberías agregar tu html y css que tienes hasta ahorita

Comment: @VictorAlvarez Código agregado. Gracias por la recomendación. No agrego el CSS porque estoy usando Bootstrap 4 y lo único que he agregado ha sido el `style=" margin-top: -50px;"`.

Comment: No termino de entender tu problema, si pudieras ser mas claro ayudaría mucho

Comment: ¿Has pensado qué va a pasar cuando el menú se colapse en pantallas más pequeñas? ¿Cómo vas a controlar la posición del logo tras esa distribución? Podría ofrecerte una respuesta, pero debes considerar que Bootstrap es _mobile-first_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que requieres necesitas usar CSS. Solo necesitas un identificador en el header para que funcione este ejemplo:

```
 #mithead:before {
  background-image: url("img/logo-rinoff.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -31px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

¿Cómo funciona? Usando ::before o ::after insertas algo antes o después del contenido.

> En CSS, **::before** crea un pseudo-elemento que es el primer hijo del elemento seleccionado. Es usado normalmente para añadir contenido estético a un elemento, usando la propiedad content.

Te proporciono un ejemplo que hice en codePen [**aquí**](https://codepen.io/Mariyselita/pen/wvByWGB?editors=1100).

[image: ejemplo]

Espero haber sido de ayuda y suerte.

Actualización a petición de Jheyman Mejia.

```css
#mithead:before {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Se%C3%B1al_Institucional_logo.svg/100px-Se%C3%B1al_Institucional_logo.svg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  left: 55%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}

header{
  background-color: #1d2124;
  height: 50%;
}

a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://static.fontawesome.com/css/fontawesome-app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="mithead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-top">
      <div class="col-sm-12 pt-2 pb-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-left mt-2 mb-2 my-auto">
            <a target="_blank" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 text-right mt-2 mb-2 my-auto">
            <a target="_blank" href="#" class="text-white btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-circle-sm m-1">
               <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" href="#" class="text-white btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-circle-sm m-1">
               <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/29/08/47/entrepreneur-696966_1280.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El código del pen lo puedes añadir a tu respuesta, aparte de eso, no veo en dicho snippet que funcione como en tu imagen, ¿Qué pasa si cambio la resolución de pantalla? ¿Cómo se adapta tu código y el logo al navbar responsivo de Bootstrap?

Comment: Actualizado. Le recuerdo que podemos agregar código de la manera en que nos acomodemos, no es obligatorio usar snippets.

Saludos.

Comment: Funcionó correctamente, ¡muchas gracias!